# Dodge points in point char with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given the data.table:

```
df = data.table(type=rep(letters[1:3], each=2), count=c(1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4), year=rep(c('2013', '2014'), 3))

type  count  year
a     1      2013
a     1      2014
b     4      2013
b     4      2014
c     4      2013
c     4      2014
```

I tried to plot the point chart and line chart to show the `count` against year:

```
p = ggplot(data=df, aes(x=year, y=count, group=type, color=type)) + geom_line() + geom_point(position=position_dodge(height=1))
```

which looks like:
[image]

It seems that the vertical dodge does not work.

If I generate the plot:

```
p = ggplot(data=df, aes(x=year, y=count, group=type, color=type)) + geom_line() + geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=1))
```

then the plot looks like:
[image]

where the horizontal dodge works.

How could I make the vertical dodge (the first plot) work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A roundabout solution: you can do horizontal dodge and flip the axes

```
p = ggplot(data=df, aes(x=count, y=year, group=type, color=type)) + 
  geom_line(position=position_dodge(width=1)) + 
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=1)) +
  coord_flip()
p
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But the `coord_flip` is not supported in a facet plot so I am still curious why the `dodge` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I consulted Hadley about the question and he replied that

> Dodging is only defined for geoms that have ymin and ymax

Details can be found in [Issue 1119](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1119#issuecomment-111114677).